# How can I upload my CSV file and keep fonts and bold lettering

Tags: csv

Every time I save my CSV file it deletes the fonts / underlines etc.
In my website I would like to have bold lettering, underlines preserved.

I'm using CSV Import PRO and all the options i have are:

- comma
- tab
- l (straight line)
- ;
- ^

Comment: You have made no effort in your question. You've even flagged it as CV's! More detail is need and you are welcome to use the shift or capslock button in order to use correct casing! -1

Answer (score 6):

If im understanding your question correctly. you are saving a CSV file that contains "formatting".

Unfortunately, CSV files can not contain formatting, as they are simply flat text files with the items delimited by a comma (the real name for these file types are comma delimited values).

In order to preserve your formatting you will need to save it as an XLSX or xls file (if using office on windows) these are not simple flat text files but instead a file that contains information on how to render the output.

[CSV description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
[xls file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel_file_format#File_formats)

The above links will help you to understand the difference.

Comment: thanks steve for the feedback.im trying to build a website on my own....and giving it a real go..however i have uploaded a CVS file and it works..im using CSV Import Pro..and i have tried uploading

Comment: thanks steve for the feedback.im trying to build a website on my own....and giving it a real go..however i have uploaded a CVS file and it works..im using CSV Import Pro..and i have tried uploading the same file in excel however it doent register on my site...do i need to change any of the CSV Field Delimiters so it can recongnise the excel file.

Comment: What you need to do is inport the csv file, into what ever storage medium you are using, then, have the website code itself create the layout and formatting using the data.